# Finding the maximum value of elements to be selected in a grid - ZIO $2009$, P$1$

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms, puzzle, dynamic-programming

[image: problem]
[image: problem]

Hello Community! The above problem you see is a problem I got wrong. :( This is ZIO $2009$, P$1$.

I tried the problem and miserably found the wrong answer as $20$. Here is how my approach goes - part (a): Notice that the largest element in the whole grid is $16$ which appears two times. I may be a good decision to start there to maximize the score but unfortunately, it is covered by only negative numbers. Although if we try to start, with the upper $16$, we get value: $16 - 9 + 13 = 20$. Similarly, starting with other big numbers we observe that the value gets even lesser so the answer must be $\boxed{20}$. However, like most trial and error attempts is optimization problems, this is wrong as the answer is $29$.

Now the main question I have for this problem is: **How do we ensure maximum value?** Is there some sort of an algorithm or something that we can follow and can be assured to have found the maximum value? Note that this problem is from a pen and paper exam where you are given 10 minutes to solve one sub-case (that is 30 minutes for this whole problem), so complete trial and error is of no use at all.

I asked a similar problem on MSE only: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3424773/an-optimization-problem-to-find-the-consecutive-day-subset-with-maximum-value) but haven't got any answers till now... Any help there would also be appreciated.

The answers are $29, 9, 20$.

I would be grateful if anyone could help.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in the upper left corner, replace each number $x$ with $x$ plus the larger of the number above it and the number to the left of it. In (a) this results in $$\matrix{-2&-1&-4&0&-4\cr10&-6&6&-6&2\cr-6&7&-7&1&-2\cr1&3&19&4&14\cr-8&19&10&23&7\cr}$$ You must exit at the bottom row or the rightmost column, and you want to exit at the biggest exit number, which is the $23$ in the bottom row. Now trace your way back to the left and up from that $23$, always choosing the larger of the two possible numbers. This takes you left to $10$, then left to $19$ (or up to $19$, it doesn't matter), then up to $3$, up to $7$, left (or up) to $-6$, up to $10$, up to $-2$. The smallest number on the way was the $-6$, so that path will give you $23-(-6)=29$, which is the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a(i,j)$ be the given values, and let $b(i,j)$ be the maximum value attainable starting from cell $(i,j)$.  Then
$$b(i,j) = a(i,j) +
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $i=j=n$}\\
\max(0,b(i,j+1)) & \text{if $i=n$ and $j<n$}\\
\max(b(i+1,j),0) & \text{if $i<n$ and $j=n$}\\
\max(b(i+1,j),b(i,j+1)) & \text{if $i<n$ and $j<n$}
\end{cases}
$$

The resulting values of $b(i,j)$ for part (a) are:

```
23  18  17  20  16 
25  13  16   1  12 
13  29   6  13   6 
23  16  20  -2  10 
13  20   4  13 -16
```

The largest value is $b(3,2) = 29$.